# how can i use lift-mongo-record with play framework?

Tags: scala, mongodb, playframework, lift

I want to use lift-mongodb-record in my play scala project.
for using. i need co configure lift-mongodb like this:

```
import com.mongodb.Mongo
import net.liftweb.mongodb.{MongoIdentifier, MongoDB}

object MainDb extends MongoIdentifier {
  val jndiName = "main"
}

MongoDB.defineDb(MainDb, new Mongo, "test")
```

where can I put mongodb initialisation, to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't actually matters where you install mongodb. You just need to know the host where you installed mongodb and port on which it running. I suppose you are running you app and installed mongo on the local computer. In this case host would be `localhost` and by default mongo accepts connections on port `27017`.

So now, you have all needed information and you need to provide it to lift like this:

```
MongoDB.defineDb(
    MainDb, 
    new Mongo(new ServerAddress("localhost", 27017)), 
    "test")
```

It's also not necessarily needed to define new DB identifier (`MainDb` in your case), you can always you `DefaultMongoIdentifier` unless you are accessing several DB instances.

In this page you can find more information about mongodb configuration:

http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/liftweb/Mongo_Configuration

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use casbah with play & scala. http://jaredrosoff.com/2011/05/getting-started-with-play-framework-scala-and-casbah/

Regards,

Serdar